# Was Ottawa, Canada the origin of the "Free Tibet" movement that became world famous in the 80's and 90's?

Tags: china, western-civilisation, tibet, newspapers

Free Tibet as a slogan [became world-famous](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=free%20tibet&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) starting from 1986-1987
[image]

And the only reference I can find as to the sparks that ignited the movement are a [demonstration in Ottawa in 1986](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/News_Tibet/I2tNi_fqd2wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22free%20tibet%22&pg=RA2-PA16&printsec=frontcover), where Tibetans walked the streets chanting "Free Tibet" with "Free Tibet" placards and flags.

Question: were these demonstrations in Canada the spark the ignited the Free Tibet movement of the 80's and 90's?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, are you asking about the origin of the movement, or the slogan? Of course the movement per se originated in Tibet. I personally would steer this question toward when faraway countries took an interest in the subject.

Comment: Presumably you've checked the history of the [Tibetan Independence Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_independence_movement) (which does suggest that global awareness originated in the "street demonstrations, perhaps specifically the 1986 Ottawa demonstration").

Comment: @Steve Bird, I just wrote that entry into Wikipedia... then I noticed that google mislabelled that news article, which dates from 1980, google wrote that it's from 1986, however the newspaper and street demonstration was in 1980, So i am probably mistaken.